# Отключить Unity в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Можно ли в Ubuntu полностью отключить графику? Оставить только консоль bash.

В общем случае можно задать вопрос так: можно ли поставить какой-нибудь Linux без графики, только с консолью bash? Причём ещё крайне желательно чтобы "из коробки" с минимальным скачиванием пакетов работал ns-3.24. В Ubuntu он работает точно, в CentOS у меня возникли проблемы.

Comment: Что такое ns-3.24?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Можно ли в Ubuntu полностью отключить графику?

да, конечно, если под «графикой» вы подразумеваете запущенный x-сервер.

а запускает его (обычно) *display manager*, который запускается как *демон* в процессе инициализации операционной системы и работает постоянно.

в вашем случае роль *display manager*-а исполняет, скорее всего, программа *gdm* (возможно, с какой-нибудь цифрой в конце).

остановить его можно (как и других *демонов*), например, так:

```
$ sudo stop gdm
```

---

совсем убрать x-сервер можно по-разному: он и сам состоит из огромного количества пакетов, и вокруг него их «завязано» ещё больше. существенная часть всех этих пакетов должна попасть в кандидаты на удаление после удаления пакета *xserver-xorg-core*:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-core
```

---

> Оставить только консоль bash

сделать это, конечно, можно, но без операционной системы (только с загрузчиком и двумя программами — `linux` и `bash`) ваш замечательный компьютер превратится в гору бесполезного хлама. операционная система — нужна.

---

> можно ли поставить какой-нибудь Linux без графики

одна лишь программа `linux` — абсолютно бесполезна. даже чтобы её загрузить нужна ещё одна программа — загрузчик (сейчас почти повсеместно это — `grub`). а после своей загрузки всё, что в состоянии сделать программа `linux` — это пожаловаться, что «она в панике и не может найти программу init» (*kernel panic no init found*).

а вот операционная система «без графики» — это вполне рабочее решение. как уже подсказали в другом ответе, вы можете скачать образ т.н. «[серверной редакции](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)» той же самой версии дистрибутива *ubuntu*. от «десктопной редакции» он отличается, по большому счёту, лишь меньшим количеством «из-коробочно» устанавливаемых пакетов — нет x-сервера и почти всего с ним связанного. а репозиторий-то — один и тот же, поэтому установкой/удалением пакетов вы легко можете превратить одну редакцию в другую уже «на месте».

Answer (score 3):

Можно скачать просто [серверный](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) образ и установить его. А если вообще минимальный набор софта, то во время установки выбрать ручной выбор пакетов.

Comment: @hunter, на всякий случай [инструкция на русском](http://faqpc.ru/kak-ustanovit-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-lts/) о скачивании и настройке серверной Убунты

Answer (score 2):

Просто вместо логина жми Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6. Там консольные окна входа для входа в консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Забейте в Google "linux без графической оболочки" и скачивайте понравившуюся